# Redirect with htaccess for images onto another server without redirect looping

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, infinite-loop

I currently have a host where my main site is hosted on. I have set up nginx on another server to mirror/cache files being requested if it doesn't have it already, in particular images and flv videos.

For example:

www.domain.com is my main site.

www.domain.com/video/video.flv

www.domain.com/images/1.png

I would like to ask apache to redirect it to imgserv.domain.com (imgserv.domain.com points to another server IP)

imgserv.domain.com/video/video.flv

imgserv.domain.com/images/1.png

Basically redirect everything with certain filetypes and preserving the structure of the URL, like flv etc.

I tried something but I am getting a redirect looping error. Could someone help me out?

Thank you!

This is what I have at the moment

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RedirectMatch 302 ^(.*)\.gif$ http://imgserv.domain.com/forums$1.gif
RedirectMatch 302 ^(.*)\.jpg$ http://imgserv.domain.com/forums$1.jpg
RedirectMatch 302 ^(.*)\.png$ http://imgserv.domain.com/forums$1.png
```

Comment: Maybe, if you let us know what you tried. And by the way, this belongs on ServerFault. (Don't repost it on the other site, this question will probably get migrated soon)

Comment: Hi David, I've added it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two different modules: `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteCond` are from [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) while `RedirectMatch` is from [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html). They can’t work together.

Try this mod_rewrite example instead:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://imgserv.example.com/forums/$0 [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi Gumbo, thanks for the reply. I have placed it in my root public_html directory however any files in the folder (example.com/picture.jpg) redirects as example.com/forums/forums/forums... /picture.jpg)

It also doesn't redirect any images in further directories, could you help?

Comment: @Jeff: Use this additional condition to skip requests that’s path does already start with `/forum/`: `RewriteCond $0 !^forums/`.