# .htaccess - If extension is .png remove directory from URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory of .png images *www.example.com/i/image.png* which is located in */var/www/html/example.com/i/image.png*

I however, also have some other .png images *www.example.com/css/glyph/image.png* which is located in */var/www/html/example.com/css/glyph/image.png*

I would like to be able to access the images in the /i/ folder from the root directory.
Example *www.example.com/image.png* will actually take me to *www.example.com/i/image.png*

Does anyone have any kind of .htaccess solution that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+\.png)$ /i/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers to this questions should help - [Redirect with htaccess for images onto another server without redirect looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050935/redirect-with-htaccess-for-images-onto-another-server-without-redirect-looping)

Specifically:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://imgserv.example.com/forums/$0 [L,R]
```